# Horizontal list inside equation

Tags: equations, lists

I'd like to have a horizontal list with roman enumeration (i.e. i), ii), iii),...) inside an equation. The idea is for each item of the list to be individually referenceable. This is what it should like:

[image]

(Image was produced using this ugly piece of code:)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
i) \, a=b, \qquad ii) \, c=d.
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You must be young. I've seen uglier code.

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly what you want, but tray, maybe you liked ...

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=2mm,preview]{standalone}
    \usepackage{array,amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\hsize}
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:i}
 \tag{i}    a=b     
    \end{equation}
\end{minipage}\quad\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\hsize}
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:ii} 
c=d  \tag{ii}
    \end{equation}\medskip        
\end{minipage}\\
Regardin\eqref{eq:i} and \eqref{eq:ii} \dots\\

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

or this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=2mm,preview]{standalone}
    \usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
    \begin{inparaenum}[i)]
\item\label{eq:i}   $a=b$  
    \qquad   
\item\label{eq:ii}  $c=d$       
    \end{inparaenum}
\end{center}
Regarding (\ref{eq:i}) and (\ref{eq:ii}) \dots\\

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
Regarding to new ask in comment, try:

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=2mm,preview]{standalone}
    \usepackage{paralist}
\newcommand{\SEref}[2]{\textbf{see eq. \ref{#1}.\ref{#2}}}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\hsize}
    \hfil\begin{inparaenum}[i)]
\item\label{eq:i}   $a=b$
    \qquad
\item\label{eq:ii}  $c=d$
    \end{inparaenum}
    \end{minipage}
\end{equation}
Regarding (\ref{eq:1}.\ref{eq:i}) and \SEref{eq:1}{eq:ii} \dots\\
    \end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Referencing not straight forward, but with new command similar to one in above code, you can slightly simplified referencing. Other way is that in the first case equation encapsulate in `begin{subequations} ... \end{subequations}.

Comment: Thanks. I like the `paralist` approach. The only thing missing is for i) and ii) to have an equation number, so that, ideally, when I reference them with `cleveref`, the result looks like **see eq. (9.i)**.

Comment: @PacificOrion, I suspect that you actually looking for sub equations, but this was not clear from your question. Unfortunately `paralist` doesn't work directly in equation environment. I will look, what can be done.

Comment: Thanks for the mentioning `subequations`. Didn't know about those yet. This time, I ended up going with manual tinkering, because there was no ideal solution. I upvoted your reply but didn't accept it as an answer yet.